# How to include omp.h in OS X?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, openmp

I'm new in C and have some problems compiling my code in OS X.

I code Java a lot both in Eclipse and use terminal to compile my code. However now I'm learning openMP and have troubles with it.

First I downloaded Xcode to write openMP code but it didn't recognize `<omp.h>`. Then I installed `g++`. When I type `g++ -v` into terminal I get this:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

But when I use `g++ Mesh.cpp -fopenmp` I still get

```
Mesh.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Then I tried to install PTP into my Eclipse and got the same problem.
I thought there was no `omp.h` in my MacBook so I searched for it and found several `omp.h` under folders under `gcc-4.9.1/build/`.

Here comes the problem. Based on the Java experience the only reason why I have the file but cannot use it is that the Class Path is wrong. However, I have no idea how to change this configuration in g++, or in Xcode, or in Eclipse. But since I can include files like `<stdio.h>` and compile it with all the IDEs, how can't I do the same with `<omp.h>`?

Another thing I noticed is that the gcc folder version is `4.9.1`, but when I type `gcc -v` into terminal I get the same with typing in `g++ -v`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Shouldn't the version information says something about `4.9.1`? Just like what `java -version` shows

```
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

Thanks for reading. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This command can help you

> brew install libomp

```
brew info libomp
libomp: stable 6.0.1 (bottled)
LLVM's OpenMP runtime library
https://openmp.llvm.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/libomp/6.0.1 (12 files, 1.2MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-11-20 at 16:12:22
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/libomp.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.10 ✔
==> Caveats
On Apple Clang, you need to add several options to use OpenMP's front end
instead of the standard driver option. This usually looks like
  -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -lomp

You might need to make sure the lib and include directories are discoverable
if /usr/local is not searched:

  -L/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include

For CMake, the following flags will cause the OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX target to
be set up correctly:
  -DOpenMP_CXX_FLAGS="-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include" -DOpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES="omp" -DOpenMP_omp_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
```

Comment: Welcome. What does it do? How will it help? Please see [answer] and take the Welcome [tour].

Comment: This is the actual solution for those of you using homebrew.

Comment: I'm back from 9 years later. This question has 82k views so for those who use homebrew, this is the answer.

Answer (score 19):

MacOS seems to have that library included but XCode can't find it if you simply use:

```
#include <omp.h>
```

However, if you don't have the library installed,you can simply add it by installing it with HomeBrew:

```
brew install libomp
```

After doing this , simply replace library include code with this one:

```
#include "/usr/local/opt/libomp/include/omp.h"
```

or the path that terminal shows you after installing libomp with brew.

Comment: What if we want to make the code platform cross-compatible?

Answer (score 16):

GCC 4.9.1 normally does not ship with OS X (actually no GCC ships with Xcode any more). Yours must have been installed by another means, e.g. Homebrew or self compilation as described [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/). What you are probably missing is properly set `PATH` variable or the additionally installed compiler has version-suffixed binaries, i.e. `gcc-4.9` or `g++-4.9` instead of simply `gcc` / `g++`.

As @rubenvb has already mentioned, Apple symlinks the Clang executables with GCC-like names. I personally find that a bad practice since recent Clang versions shipped with Xcode react on unrecognised command-line options (e.g. GCC frontend specific ones) with hard errors.

Comment: I installed GCC exactly followed the link you mentioned, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: If you followed the instructions on the linked page, then your compiler is named `g++-4.9` and you must explicitly add the path to it unless you installed into `/usr/local/bin`. Also, you have to reconfigure PTP to call `g++-4.9` instead of `g++`.

Comment: Thanks! After typing "export PATH=/usr/gcc-4.9.1/bin:$PATH", I can use "g++-4.9" now.

Answer (score 13):

The `gcc` and `g++` commands are not what you think they are with XCode: Apple thought it would be a good idea to masquerade Clang as GCC to make the transition smoother.

Clang OpenMP support is still being worked on. If I didn't miss any big release of the WIP code, you'll need to build [this version of clang](http://clang-omp.github.io/) and use that.

You can of course always install a real GCC through stuff like homebrew or macports, that will come with OpenMP support.

Comment: So basically the problem is GCC in my laptop is a fake by Clang? Since the latter one doesn't support openMP, it cause all the problem? Thank you.

Comment: @user3928256 Yeah, the `gcc` command which you execute is provided by XCode, and is just Clang, really. I did miss the part of your question where you mention installing GCC 4.9.1. So, if you set up your PATH as described by @Hristo, you should be fine.

Comment: Update from the linked website: Development activity of OpenMP support in clang/llvm compiler has moved to www.llvm.org. Please get OpenMP-enabled clang (OpenMP 3.1 is fully supported in clang/llvm 3.7) and contribute to its further development there. This web-site is maintained for archival purposes only.

Comment: If you `brew install gcc` you can run the real gcc as `gcc-6`. Seriously Apple, that's some weird sh...

Answer (score 6):

The `omp.h` file has been moved to a subdirectory. I found it in MacPorts and solved this compilation problem by creating a link to this file:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/libomp/omp.h /opt/local/include/omp.h
```

Comment: MacPorts has a variant for this: `sudo port install libomp +top_level`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using M1 chip

brew install libomp here `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/`

so you have to link the libomp manually, after I installed `brew install libomp`, I got `libomp 14.0.0`

so use following command might help you

```
 g++ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp  -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/14.0.0/include -L/usr/local/lib -lomp  *.cpp -o main
```

Comment: I had to run `ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/14.0.5/include/omp.h omp.h` from the project folder

Answer (score 0):

after `brew install libomp`
you can use `brew --prefix libomp` to get the root directory for the installed package.

```
LIBOMP_ROOT=$(brew --prefix libomp) g++ prog.cpp -I $LIBOMP_ROOT/include -L $LIBOMP_ROOT/lib -l omp
```