# omp.h not found, OS X Yosemite not using newest gcc version

Tags: xcode, gcc, openmp, osx-yosemite

I am trying to build GraphChi on OS X Yosemite but get the following error:

`fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found`

From this question - [How to include omp.h in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990296/how-to-include-omp-h-in-os-x) - I learned that Yosemite uses Clang instead of gcc, which does not include omp.h.

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Next, I installed gcc via Homebrew

```
$ brew info gcc
gcc: stable 4.9.2 (bottled)
http://gcc.gnu.org
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1 (1092 files, 177M)
Built from source with: --without-multilib
```

and updated `$PATH` to include the path to the new gcc version

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1:usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

however, `gcc -v` and `which gcc` still point to the old version, and building GraphChi still doesn't work due to the missing omp.h file

Does anyone know what else I need to do?

**Update**

`locate omp.h` returned:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/omp.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/4.9.2/include/omp.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2/include/omp.h
```

my `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/4.9.2/include:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/bin:usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: Try `locate "omp.h"`. If you haven't configured `locate`, I recommend doing it -- it'll take a minute or so, but you'll find exactly where it is, so you can add that to your path.

Comment: Also, if `gcc -v` still points to the old version, edit your `~/.bashrc` and reinstantiate your terminal.

Comment: I already reinstantiated my terminal, that is why the path is already pointing to the correct directory

Comment: export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/bin:$PATH

Comment: I tried locating omp.h and added its location to $PATH, but it's still not helping. I am editing the path in ~/.profile, is that correct or does it make a difference where I do this?

Comment: Post what `locate` returned and what you have in your ~/.profile

Comment: see update of my question above

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with installing `gcc` with homebrew:

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

and then building the source code with

```
CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 cmake ..
CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 make -j7
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have installed gcc-4.9 with homebrew, it will automatically be in your path. To use OpenMP, you just need to make sure you are using the newly installed gcc-4.9, and it will be able to find omp.h.

In the case of GraphChi, you will have to go change line 3 of the Makefile to be gcc-4.9. From there, running make should just work. They describe this in their README, but at least the version they describe is out of date https://github.com/GraphChi/graphchi-cpp#problems-compiling-on-mac.

Answer (score 0):

`clang` does not support OpenMP yet. Also `gcc` by default links to Apple's LLVM clang compiler (not the GCC installed from brew).
Instead `gcc-4.9` would link to GCC. I think if `-fopenmp` is specified `omp.h` is included automatically.

It is possible to manually build a version of clang with OpenMP support, see http://clang-omp.github.io

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the include path to `PATH`; instead, specify it as `CFLAGS`, including the `-I` option. You can `export` the `CFLAGS` variable, or set it on the fly.

Depending on how you compile things, you could do

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/4.9.2/include/omp.h gcc <whatever>
```

Of course, in this case you can specify it directly on the `gcc` command (as `-I/usr/local/....`), but the `CFLAGS` variable also works with `configure` (as configure often won't have an option to specify where it should look for specific include files); probably with `make`, or even for those installing a Python package: `CFLAGS=-I... pip install <some-package>`.

Other flags to consider are

- `CXXFLAGS`: C++ specific pre-processor flags
- `LDFLAGS`: linker specific flags (e.g. `LDFLAGS=-L/some/path/...` for linking with dynamic libraries).
- `CC`: specify the C compiler to use. This is an easy way to avoid the built-in `gcc` alias for `clang` on OS X. Just use `CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4 make` or similar.
- `CXX`: specify the C++ compiler to use.