# How to set up basic openMP project in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, openmp, clion

I am trying to run simple `OpenMP` program in `CLion IDE`.
When I run it I get an ERROR:

```
CMakeFiles\openmp_test_clion.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
D:/.../openmp_test_clion/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to 'omp_get_thread_num'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    int id;
#pragma omp parallel private(id)
    {
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("%d: Hello World!\n", id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(openmp_test_clion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(openmp_test_clion ${SOURCE_FILES})

message(STATUS "Checking OpenMP")
find_package(OpenMP)
IF(OPENMP_FOUND)
    message("Found OpenMP!)
    # add flags for OpenMP
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
ELSE()
    message("Missed OpenMP!")
ENDIF()
```

Here is screen of my toolchains:
[image]

I have zero experience with `OpenMP` and I am beginner programmer in `C++` so please give me a bit of an explanation how to setup my project.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So after a while I figured it out. I changed CmakeLists.txt as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(openmp_test_clion)

# added -fopenmp
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fopenmp")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(openmp_test_clion ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

And I needed to install openmp via [TDM-GCC installer](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) .

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404666/1662425) shows a better setup that supports multiple compilers, rather than hardcoding the gcc flags.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. This was the only answer that worked for me on Mac OS with CLion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203252/osx-and-clion-cant-find-omp-h