# Set the OpenMP project MacOS Mojave in CLion

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, openmp

I'm trying to execute my homework in C++ with OpenMP on Mac with macOS Mojave. But it's failed. The Mac is new, so all setups are not changed. What I did:

1. I installed Homebrew.
2. I installed llvm (brew install llvm)
3. I installed omp (brew install libomp)

Also, in CMakeLists.txt of the project I have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(...)

include_directories("/usr/local/include" "/usr/local/opt/llvm/include")
link_directories("/usr/local/lib" "/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native -fopenmp -O3")

add_executable(...)
```

In Terminal 'clang -v':

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

'gcc -v':

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

In CLion I have this error:

```
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable search
ld: unknown option: -platform_version
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [search] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/search.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/search.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [search] Error 2
```

I re-read a lot of forums, but I still don’t understand what the problem may be.

Comment: Why do you run `clang -v` and `gcc -v` in the Terminal when your `CMakeLists.txt` says your compiler is `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++`

Comment: I just wanted to show you what version of clang and gcc I use, may be here my mistake is..

Comment: The version outputs you get in the terminal are from Apple's command-line LLVM compilers, not the ones installed by Homebrew. Homebrew never installs anything outside `/usr/local` (except casks) and `clang -v` clearly reports being installed in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to call the *Xcode preprocessor* to handle OMP.

C++ flags should include:
`-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -lomp -I/usr/local/include`

LDFLAGS should include:
`-lomp`

With cmake you may add them to your command:
`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -lomp -I/usr/local/include" -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-lomp" ..`

or you may add them to your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Nothing wrong with AppleClang, it works with OpenMP via the Xcode preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

After trying so many options from the following links

- [How to set up basic openMP project in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531078/how-to-set-up-basic-openmp-project-in-clion)
- [How to set linker flags for OpenMP in CMake's try_compile function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399422/how-to-set-linker-flags-for-openmp-in-cmakes-try-compile-function/12404666#12404666)
  .. and some more

I had the error `The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: g++-6 is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.`
So

1. i installed GNU gcc from brew instead of Clang (gcc@12 was installed)

```
 brew install gcc
```

2. Changed the c++ and c compilers in `Preferences > Build, Execution and Development > Toolchains` in CLion to the installed compilers in `1`

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc-12 // c
/usr/local/bin/g++-12 // c++
```

3. My CMakeList.txt file at this point looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_compile_options(test PRIVATE -Wall ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS})
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS})
```

and it worked for me.