# Proper way to use omp.h in macOS

Tags: c++, macos, openmp

When trying to compile ASIFT algorithm from C++ source on macOS, I encountered problems with OpenMP library.

The compiler is Apple Clang, macOS version is 11.3.

First the compiler told me that "omp.h" can't be found. I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60831839/12524821) and installed `libomp` through HomeBrew. After proper installation, I change the following code in source file:

```
#include "omp.h"
```

to:

```
#include "/usr/local/opt/libomp/include/omp.h"
```

This resolves the previous "omp.h not found" error.

***However***, the project source can still not be compiled properly after executing `make` command. Clang throw a linker error. The terminal output is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_omp_get_num_procs", referenced from:
      compute_asift_matches(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> > > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> > > > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> > > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<keypoint, std::__1::allocator<keypoint> > > > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<keypoint, keypoint>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<keypoint, keypoint> > >&, siftPar&) in compute_asift_matches.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [demo_ASIFT] Error 1
```

I also write a much simpler code in Xcode just for test:

```
#include "/usr/local/opt/libomp/include/omp.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num = omp_get_num_procs();
    std::cout<<num<<std::endl;
}
```

The code can't be compiled properly.

It seems that the compiler can't find implementation of the function `omp_get_num_procs()` declared in `omp.h`.

For reference, here is the declaration of `omp_get_num_procs()` in `omp.h` (line 69):

```
extern int    __KAI_KMPC_CONVENTION  omp_get_num_procs    (void);
```

I'm not sure whether it's a compiler parameter issue or OpenMP wasn't installed properly. I have confirmed that `libomp.a` and `libomp.dylib` are placed correctly in `/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib` directory.

Can anyone kindly give some advice on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should link libomp.a to a project. [Here](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xcode-link-static-lib.asp) example how to link static lib to Xcode C++ project.

Comment: That works! After linking libomp.a to the project, both Xcode and command line Clang compiles properly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Apple compilers do not (at least in public) support OpenMP. The necessary headers and libraries are missing for a reason!

Your best bet is therefore to install a compiler which does (using [brew](https://brew.sh/), or [macPorts](https://www.macports.org/) depending on how you are supporting other tools which don't come from Apple).

To answer your specific question: "Proper way to use omp.h in macOS", the answer is "Install a compiler that supports OpenMP."

Comment: Thanks. The OpenMP library installed through HomeBrew works, and Clang compiles properly after linking libomp.a to the project, as mentioned in another answer by @Borys.

Comment: It is generally safer to use a dynamic version of libomp, rather than statically link llibomp.a. (This can avoid avoid problems is you link against another library [e.g. some BLAS] which was compiled with a different OpenMP compiler...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Will further look into this problem when possible.