# ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-pysap

Tags: python, installation

I keep encoutering this issue when downloading PySAP.

After I run the command line `pip install --user python-pysap` as instructed in the installation guide (https://github.com/CEA-COSMIC/pysap), I keep having this error in the end:

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-pysap
  Running setup.py clean for python-pysap
Failed to build python-pysap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-pysap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have tried to download the wheel of python-pysap here ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)) but found nothing.

The rest of the error is too long so I put them in a txt file and you can find this txt file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P7NYJipukCZ3hMFOmmSnBcksbVBHAogK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You would need to show the rest of the error.

Comment: `fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found` – see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990296/how-to-include-omp-h-in-os-x